# iOS - Connect UITableViewCell to another ViewController Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview, xcode5

I have programmatically created a tableView populated it with some rows. However, I was wondering upon tapping one of these cells how could I navigate to another view controller while passing data to the other viewController as well?

This is what I filled each cell with:

`cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", currentAccount.username];`

How do I pass `currentAccount.username` to another viewController I just created? I am not using storyboards as I had created the UITableView programmatically. However, I have created another view controller called `FeedViewController`.

Comment: Don't just set the text on those cells and forget about which cell you set that text on. Views are just for displaying data. So you should actually model your data. For very simple example, create an array of strings, and each index of that array represents what you're going to fill in for each cell. Then when the user taps on a cell, you already know according to your array of strings, which one they tapped (the method that fires when a user taps a cell includes the `indexPath` for that cell, that should map to your array of strings)

Comment: @mattyohe Interesting, but suppose I have that indexPath, how do I send that to another View Controller?

Comment: You would create that next view controller in the didSelectCell code, and pass any information onto that new view controller before you push it onto the navigation controller stack.

Comment: Search "passing data between controllers", there are thousands of questions and answers on this topic here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

In your table view delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you would instantiate your FeedViewController, pass any data to it using its properties and then display it.

Something like:

```
FeedViewController* feedVC = [[FeedViewController alloc] init];
feedVC.username = currentAccount.username
[self presentViewController:feedVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```